# Client-side routing doesn't work after SSR in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've added server-side rendering to React app and it works when you go directly to those URLs, but Link components just change url in search bar and UI stays the same.

Does anyone know potential solution?

P.S.
I've updated to React and ReactDOM 16.0 and using hydrate() instead of render().

Answer (score 0):

Update:
I just needed to pass main component to withRouter HOC.